# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass error shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this view called "_filters.html.erb' where i am trying to  display the data from different models  and i am getting the error.

```
Task <%= select_tag :timesheet_task_id, options_from_collection_for_select([unspecified_task], 'id', 'name', @timesheet_task_id) + grouped_options_for_select(grouped_task_options, @timesheet_task_id), prompt: '<All Tasks>' %>
```

I am getting this error "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"
 can anyone help me with it?

In the console when i try to query the same thing  i am getting an object 
EX: `TimesheetTask.where(name:'No Specified task').first`
I get this object returned as 
`TimesheetTask id: 82, name: "No Specified task", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, parent_id: nil, active: nil`

unspecified_task is

def unspecified_task
    TimesheetTask.where(name: NO_SPECIFIC[:task]).first
 end

NO_SPECIFIC = {
  project: '(No specific project)',
  task: '(No Specified task)'
}

Comment: what is `unspecified_task`?

Comment: def unspecified_task
    TimesheetTask.where(name: NO_SPECIFIC[:task]).first
end                                                                                                                NO_SPECIFIC = {
  project: '(No specific project)',
  task: '(No Specified task)'
}